# Issue on print page

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

I have problem with printing charts on my page.

There are charts in my website all I want is to allow user to print in webbrowser. I have already collapsed not nessesary text using css.

My problem is that chart is not fit to print page. Below there is an example:
[image]

In website charts goes to 22:00 on X axis.

All I found was

```
@page {
    size: auto; /* auto is the initial value */
    /* this affects the margin in the printer settings */
    margin: 25mm 25mm 25mm 25mm;
}
```

It doesnt solve problem

EDIT:
I am using [hightcharts.js](http://www.highcharts.com/)

Also used

```
@page {
    overflow: visible
}
```

It shows whole chart but it get out of border

Comment: Are the charts just images? Because it *looks* like the image is simply overflowing it's bounds. Post the rest of your code so we can be sure :)

Comment: did you use the exporting.js along with highchart also ?

Comment: yes i am using exporting.js